# How to compute $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\cosh((n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi)}$

Tags: theta-functions

How to compute $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\cosh((n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi)}$?

My attempt was trying to consider the Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$ and use the inverse Mellin transform as a representation of $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$

$$\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}=\mathcal{M}^{-1}\Big(2\Gamma(s)\beta(s)\Big)(x) $$
Which implies
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\cosh((n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma +i\infty}2^{s+1} \frac{\Gamma(s)\beta^2(s)}{\pi^s}\, ds$$

This integral didn't lead me anywhere.

I did realize the series may be similar to a particular value of theta functions, but I couldn't find any that arrives to this sum.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is $\beta$ the Dirichlet beta function?

Comment: Without the alternating signs (ie factor $(-1)^n$) we do have a closed form in terms of theta and elliptic functions. But the alternating signs are creating problem in getting a closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/%7Edieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#SeriesxofxHyperbolicxFunctions) website (See "Hyperbolic series involving the lemniscate functions") we have:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{\cosh \left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi \right)}=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } (-1)^m
   \text{sech}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}+m\right) \pi \right)=\\\frac{i \log (1+\text{sech}(\pi ))}{\pi }-\frac{i \psi _{e^{-4 \pi
   }}^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}\right)}{\pi }+\frac{2 i \psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}\right)}{\pi
   }+\frac{i \psi _{e^{-2 \pi }}^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)}{\pi }-\frac{2 i \psi _{e^{-\pi
   }}^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)}{\pi }$$

Mathematica code:

`(I*Log[1 + Sech[Pi]])/Pi - (I*QPolyGamma[0, 1/4 - I/4, E^(-4*Pi)])/Pi + ((2*I)*QPolyGamma[0, 1/4 - I/4, E^(-2*Pi)])/Pi +  (I*QPolyGamma[0, 1/2 - I/2, E^(-2*Pi)])/Pi - ((2*I)*QPolyGamma[0, 1/2 - I/2, E^(-Pi)])/Pi`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the website couldn't render the formulas

Comment: @Dqrksun .You have to wait a little bit.